# How to stop clients from changing webpage data with inspector?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Ok, this is a problem I have been dealing with for some time.

My page loads with some `li` elements. All of them have their own id, which is their `primary_key` id in the database. Each element can be removed from the database. The process of removing is done by jQuery's `$.POST` method, getting the id of that element and passing it to a PHP file which gets the id and removes the corresponding record from the database.

In Google or Firefox's inspector, if I change the id value of an element, then press the remove button of that element, a different element with that id is removed.

Example: We want to remove "Mohsen" with id 45 from database.

```
<script>
   $('li').click(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr(id);
      $.post('delete.php',
         {r_id: id}
      );
   });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<li id="45">mohsen</li>
<li id="35">vahid</li>
<li id="25">neda</li>
```

The code above is as originally loaded. When i click on "mohsen", "mohsen" gets removed from the database, since he has the id of **45**. But, if I use the inspector and change the id values to:

```
<li id="25">mohsen</li>
<li id="35">vahid</li>
<li id="45">neda</li>
```

Now, when "mohsen" is clicked, "neda" which had `primary_key` id value of **25** in the database is deleted instead, which we did not mean to allow.

Is there any way to stop a user from manipulating the markup data with an inspector? In another words, how do I remove "Mohsen" from the database properly, even if its id value is tampered with?
**Note:** mohsen was an example, and each of `li` can be removed.

Comment: Why does this even matter? The inspector change is only local. The user cannot make anyone else mistakenly delete one of the elements. If 'moshen' and 'neda' are both available for deletion, whatever the user does with inspector is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @JeremyB. so it doesn't matter 1 user can possibly delete all the records in the table?

Comment: @Anzeo. What? first if there is no validation, that is not the fault of the browsers inspector. Second, if a user is switching already available id's around in the inspector, there is no issue here. If I can already delete id: 25 or 45 and I change which button does it, that doesn't affect anything. The first rule of web apps is never trust the client. The inspector is irrelevant.

Comment: @JeremyB. My point is, this change is not just "local". If I would change the ids to something else (like in the OP's question), e.g. an id that is not listed but that can be guessed because the keys are sequential, then I could simply replace the value with anything I'd want.

Comment: @Anzeo - then your server side code should only permit you to delete items from those that you are permitted to...

Comment: @Paddy agreed, that's a possible solution. I was just pointing out this matters :)

Comment: @Anzeo just try it for yourself on facebook, but not fro removing, instead for likeing a post or comment, replace two different comment data-r attribute values and then click 'Like', see what happens? i tried once the result was that even i replaced the value of two comment, the one comment on which i had clicked took no affect on the page, but after i refreshed page the one that i had clicked was liked!!

Comment: @Kordkandi You don't have to convince me this is an issue, I understand what you mean :)

Comment: @Kordkandi: would you please tell you want to stop browser's inspector or you want to stop some 1 from deleting records?

Comment: @Anzeo i think you are right and i read other answers nice answers, i was just a bit in hurry, so don't get mad on me ;)

Comment: @noobie-php none :D! i am just trying to prevent users from deleting something which points to another thing(by data-id replacement) and the other thing can be both anyone's post or comment or that person's other comment.

Comment: @Kordkandi: then i guess you need to rephrase your question a little as you can see the amount of answers/opinion you are getting .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to reduce manipulation attempts would be not to delete by ID, but some unique random hash. You can either take that random hash as your primary key, or you create an extra column in your database.

`data_tbl(id (pk), hash, value)`

If your hash looks like: `a89x1uAp3` for example, it'll be very very hard to figure out the hashes for other records based on that hash.

Just don't pass your ID via post, but your hash and the problem is restrained pretty much.

Comment: This is also a recommended approach. Don't expose your primary keys. Even with a hash it would be possible a user can delete other records, so you'ds still need some sort of validation.

Comment: This still doesn't stop someone from guessing away - depending on how many records you are talking about, the chances of getting a random collision will change.  This should be about server side validation of a users right to remove something.

Comment: @Paddy that should be considered anyway. See in my answer I never stated that it'd be impossible to guess a hash though. Of course guessing still will be possible. But based on your hash it can be made exteremly hard to do so. User rights are another topic.

Comment: Additionally, this makes debugging your application a lot harder, for little or no additional benefit...

Answer (score 5):

You cannot prevent the users to use inspectors to see the page, the only thing you can do is to implement your own server side validation if you wish to prevent deleting of some records.

Also, if possible, try to not expose your primary keys, only some derived information, like an hash as @Thomas David Plat suggests.

Comment: Actually i did not meant to stop users to use inspectors. My question in another words is that for example in facebook when you want to remove a comment you simply click on a button and it's done. if you look at the code it has some data attribute 'data-r' that is used for storing the comment's info like its c_id in database for deletion, so if we replace two comment's this attributes value and then click the remove button of one, the one we meant is gonna be removed or the other one??

Comment: I would say "the other one", but I am pretty sure that FB implements a good server side validation, which is exactly what I suggested in my answer. Since I do not know your data structures and algorithms, I didn't go deep in the topic, you should come up with your own validation method.

Comment: You know i have had some server side validations like that a person can only remove his own comments and some other, but again if a user has posted two comments for the same post and replaces both their values, we have the problem again, of course as JeremyB said it's not a big deal for me that someone tries to remove one or his other comment, but i just wondered how to stop even this kind of things.

Comment: I think that, if you have such problem, you might have some error in your validation, in fact user A might change the ID in the HTML code for some comment, but if, at the time of deletion, the ID to delete does not belong to user A, then deletion should be denied.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot Prevent user from viewing/ changing data from inspector. The only thing you can do is to make server side validation e.g from client side send text which in your case can be "Neda","Mohsen" etc and 1st validate if that specific ID belong to that text/name. But this is purely server side thing, but AFA client side is concerned you cannot do it.

Comment: Using JavaScript has got nothing to do with this issue. You can't circumvent this security risk by not using JavaScript.

Comment: in his current Context , and OP question he was asking how to stop some 1 from modifying values, as in his post he displayed Jquery function, so if he posts whole data to that page then there is no use of JS in CURRENT scenario, thats what i was referring

Comment: It does not change the fact that removing JavaScript won't solve the issue. If the form was just posted (without AJAX) and the id's were still read from the HTML, then you'd stil encounter the issue.

Comment: @Anzeo: I agree to that but please see he dont want any 1 to change value from Client side via browser's inspector, so he must either change his question phrase a little or do as guided in some of the answers that are told.

Comment: I agree s/he needs to look into the answers, and I'm sure s/he will, otherwise s/he wouldn't have asked it in the first place :)